# Find columns in rows in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table (SoilSheet):

```
ID | FieldID | SAMP_NUM | LINE_NUM | Year
```

The LINE_NUM column is a value between 1 and 25. I need to FIND DISTINCT SAMP_NUM and FieldID ROWS that have LINE_NUM rows and return them in a single row.

In SQL Server, I can do this (shortened to only return the first 5 LINE_NUM columns and it works nearly instantly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S1.L1, S2.L2, S3.L3, S4.L4, S5.L5, 
  S.FieldID, S.SAMP_NUM FROM SoilSheet S
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID, LINE_NUM AS L1 
  FROM SoilSheet WHERE YEAR = 2013 AND LINE_NUM = 1) S1 
  ON S1.SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM AND S1.FieldID = S.FieldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID, LINE_NUM AS L2 
  FROM SoilSheet WHERE YEAR = 2013 AND LINE_NUM = 2) S2 
  ON S2.SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM AND S2.FieldID = S.FieldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID, LINE_NUM AS L3 
  FROM SoilSheet WHERE YEAR = 2013 AND LINE_NUM = 3) S3 
  ON S3.SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM AND S3.FieldID = S.FieldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID, LINE_NUM AS L4 
  FROM SoilSheet WHERE YEAR = 2013 AND LINE_NUM = 4) S4 
  ON S4.SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM AND S4.FieldID = S.FieldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID, LINE_NUM AS L5 
FROM SoilSheet WHERE YEAR = 2013 AND LINE_NUM = 5) S5 
  ON S5.SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM AND S5.FieldID = S.FieldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID, LINE_NUM AS L10 
FROM SoilSheet WHERE YEAR = 2013 AND LINE_NUM = 10) S10 
  ON S10.SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM AND S10.FieldID = S.FieldID
WHERE Year = 2013 AND 
  (SELECT ID FROM Fields WHERE ID=S.FieldID) IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY S.SAMP_NUM, S.FieldID
```

and I get this

```
L1   | L2   | L3   | L4   | L5   | FieldID | SAMP_NUM
1    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 289508  | 4416
1    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 291501  | 4417
NULL | NULL |   3  | NULL | NULL | 291339  | 4418
NULL |    2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 291390  | 4418
1    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 291535  | 4418
1    |    2 |    3 | NULL | NULL | 287808  | 4470
NULL | NULL | NULL |    4 |    5 | 287811  | 4470
```

However, when converted to MS Access, this takes forever.  I've also tried the below which is a lot slower in SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
(SELECT LINE_NUM FROM SoilSheet WHERE LINE_NUM = 1 AND Year = 2013 
AND FieldID = S.FieldID AND SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM) AS L1,
(SELECT LINE_NUM FROM SoilSheet WHERE LINE_NUM = 2 AND Year = 2013 
AND FieldID = S.FieldID AND SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM) AS L2,
(SELECT LINE_NUM FROM SoilSheet WHERE LINE_NUM = 3 AND Year = 2013 
AND FieldID = S.FieldID AND SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM) AS L3,
(SELECT LINE_NUM FROM SoilSheet WHERE LINE_NUM = 4 AND Year = 2013 
AND FieldID = S.FieldID AND SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM) AS L4,
(SELECT LINE_NUM FROM SoilSheet WHERE LINE_NUM = 5 AND Year = 2013 
AND FieldID = S.FieldID AND SAMP_NUM = S.SAMP_NUM) AS L5,
FieldID, SAMP_NUM FROM SoilSheet S
WHERE Year = 2013 AND (SELECT ID FROM Fields WHERE ID = S.FieldID) 
IS NOT NULL ORDER BY S.SAMP_NUM, S.FieldID
```

but also takes forever in Access.  Is there a way to do this in Access?

Comment: Well, never mind, I found a way to do it:

Comment: You should look at the PIVOT command in SQL Server since 25 outer joins isn't the most efficient route. I haven't worked with Access in a while, but I believe TRANSFORM is the equivalent.

Comment: You can answer your own question to let other knows about that

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
TRANSFORM LINE_NUM AS L
SELECT SAMP_NUM, FieldID FROM SoilSheet WHERE Year = 2013
GROUP BY SAMP_NUM, FieldID  
PIVOT LINE_NUM
```